# Multiple Controls Alignment dynamically in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

HI ALL

I'm a beginner in SilverLight.I have three controls in a canvas which are dynamically created.I want to align the Controls like  in Visual Studio(Left Align,Right Align, Center Align) dynamically.

I want to know whether i can select a  control dynamically?

I want to know whether i can select a Multiple control ?

Whether there is any Control Collection to group all the controls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to group these controls in another `Panel` type such a `Grid` or `StackPanel` then add that `Panel` as child to the `Canvas`.

Try this [Introduction to Panels](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article872-introduction-to-panels--silverlight-tutorial-chapter-3-.aspx) article to get a handle on the availabe options before you go any further.

Comment: I think my question was not so clear.I'm going to drag and drop controls. After i drag and drop my controls i'm going to align those controls like in Visual Studio.Can we Select a control?Which Control is selected First.?Whether there is any collections group.?